# PHP error: “syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';'”

Tags: php, sql

I get the following syntax error syntax error, unexpected 'priceid' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' while giving this code:

```
<?php

   $listObject = new webLists($DBH); 
   $price = $listObject->getPricesForUser($_SESSION['userData']['user_id']); 

   foreach ($price as $key => $value) { 

         echo '<tr><td>'.date('d F, Y', strtotime($value['date'])).
              '</td><td>'."&nbsp"."&pound;".$value['value'].
              '</td><td>'.
              '<button class = "button" data-id = $value['priceid'] data-toggle="modal" class="edit" data-target="#editPrice"><i class="material-icons"> create</i></button>'.'</td></tr>';
   }
?>
```

Comment: Look at the color highlighting at `data-id = "$value['`.

Comment: should it be data-id = $value['priceid'] ?

Comment: Concatenate like you've done elsewhere.  `data-id = ' . $value['priceid'] . '` You also should remove the spaces between the `=`s in the HTML.